# Redirect to all files in the directory

Tags: unix, awk, nawk

Using awk, how can i redirect the data to all files in the directory?

like ,lets say i want to redirect to file.txt i will do:

```
echo "abc"|awk '{print >"file.txt"}'
```

how can i acheive the same thing but to multiple files(in fact all files) in the directory.
there are some .txt files in teh cirrent directory.
so i want to redirect abc to all the files in the current directory which have an extension of .txt.

Comment: maybe with command `tee`

Comment: I have added more descripton of what i need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo abc|awk '{print |"tee files"}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tee`:

```
echo "abc" | tee files/*
```

If the directory with all these files are in `/files/`.

Comment: I know this.i needed a solution inside awk.

Answer (score 0):

One way using `GNU awk`:

```
awk -v str="abc" '{ print str > FILENAME; nextfile }' *.txt
```

This command will overwrite all the content of all files with `txt` extension with the string `abc`. You will need the `GNU` version because of the `nextfile` instruction, that closes current file and begin to process the next one.